# Mail sent twice or more instead of once using rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working with rails 3.2 and ruby 2.1.2p95. Through my application, sending 1000+ of emails. I want to send few email from smtp and few emails from sendgrid. So I have configured like below in Notifier.rb file

```
after_filter :set_delivery_options, :except => [:method1]

def set_delivery_options
  message.delivery_method.settings.merge!(
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "xxxxxxxx",
    :user_name => "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    :password => "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    :authentication => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  )
end
```

My method is like below:

```
def customer_mailing(customer)
  mail(
    :to => customer.user.email,
    :subject => "Testing",
    #:bcc => EMAIL_BCC,
    :content_type => "text/html"
  )

  set_headers
end
```

Whenever I call the above method, the mail is sending twice or more in some times on production server.

Comment: Where are you defining `set_delivery_options`. That looks like you are doing that in a controller

Comment: In same notifier.rb, I have placed set_delivery_options method using "include AbstractController::Callbacks"

Comment: Please give some suggestion about this issue, I am getting this issue on production server.